Vectorization of nested for loops with condition in NumPy
I have the following Python snippet to count the number of times the elements x and y (from X and Y) verify the conditions x<=i and y<=j concomitantly, where i and j are indices:
import numpy as np

X = np.array([ 8,  7,  9,  5,  3,  2,  4, 10,  6,  1])
Y = np.array([ 1,  3, 10,  9,  5,  7,  8,  2,  6,  4])

n = len(X)

count = 0
expected_count = 0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        count += np.sum((X <= (i+1)) & (Y <= (j+1)))
        expected_count += (i + 1) * (j + 1) / n

It works fine, but for performance reasons, I'd like to vectorize this operation.
I know that
i_ = np.arange(1, n+1)
j_ = np.arange(1, n+1)
m_ = i_[:, None] * j_[None, :]

Produces a nxn matrix m_ whose elementwise sum will return expected_count, and seems to be a way to go for count too. But I lack some more NumPy knowledge to implement the condition.
How can I achieve this, particularly vectorize the (X <= (i+1)) & (Y <= (j+1)) operation in this context?

You can use:
count = ((X <= i_[:,None]) & (Y  <= j_[:,None])[:,None]).sum()
count
285

expected_count = m_.sum()/n
302.5


It seems there is a mathematical relation to what you are doing:
Try
((n + 1 - Y) * (n + 1 - X)).sum()
285

Simplifying the equation above, and taking the fact that Y and X contains the values 1...n, we end up with the expression sum(X * Y)
sum(X * Y)
285

X @ Y
285

Also note that the expected can be easily calculated using mathematical formula. ie sum(X)* sum(Y)/n  = [n(n+1)/2]**2/n = n(n+1)**2/4
n*(n + 1)**2/4
302.5


Many thanks @Onyambu! My initial nested 'for' loops would need hours to process all my data, your last suggestion does that in 0.2s! Plus, I assume I don't need to worry about overflow when using X @ Y and n*(n+1)**2/4. Just as a curiosity, this piece of code seeks to implement the correlation coefficient from https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/copBasic/html/wolfCOP.html, since it's missing in pandas library. Thanks again!

@lukewarn the formulation I gave assumes that X and Y contains all the digits from 1...n with none missing. It wont work in case X,Y are random numbers and/or have repeated numbers

I think it will always be the case because I apply .rank(method='average') to both vectors in a step before. So the numbers are always 1,...,n and the repeated ones are averaged.

@lukewarn that is a problem. Using 'average' as the ties method will led to having floats. But the formulation only works with integers as the indices can only be integers. Just ensure the ranks are unique, and no number skipped, then the method should work. Of course you can always check the formulation against the for-loop

@lukewarn I am not sure what wolfCOP is, but hope you solve the task
